# Input textbox in a table not allowing any entry in Firefox

Tags: php, html, firefox, html-table

I am trying to populate an HTML table dynamically in a PHP `for` loop. I need two input textboxes to be loaded for entering values which I will be accessing and saving to the database later. It is working fine in IE and Chrome.

In Firefox, however, the textboxes don't allow any input. Not even the cursor appears when clicked on the textbox.

The code is too big to post here; I have posted a snippet:

```
<td>
    <input type="text" name="txtTask[]" style="width: 50px;" class="invoiceText" />
</td>
```

Comment: If your code is not confidential, please post some code here. From your description, we can't get your exact problem.

Comment: Hey and welcome to SO . Please read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/about about the type of questions which can be posted here .In short , show us what you have tried so far ;)

Comment: The code is too big to post here! :-( the <td> element with the textbox looks as below...   <td><input type="text" name="txtTask[]" style="width: 50px;" class="invoiceText" /></td>

Comment: Does it work when u try 'tabbing' through it ?

Comment: post the code which is present during inspect element for textbox

Comment: Works fine on my site, without the css-class you're using.
It might be your CSS which is causing the problem.

Comment: On a different note, I would advise you not to use inline styling. It is good that you have given a class name for your textbox. Please write CSS styling within <style> tags. Just a CodingEthicsNazi here.. :)

Comment: This could also happen if PHP is not done sending data to the browser and due to the document ready event is not fired. Forms are blocked until the ready event is fired. It has occured to me. Check your PHP output and make sure that it gets over on time.

Comment: @harsha yes, it works while tabbing through it....

Comment: @Nilesh  here is the code in the inspect element <input type="text" class="invoiceText" style="width: 50px;" name="txtTask[]">

Comment: i got the solution! it was due to the "disableSelection()" mentioned for the table's class...... i removed that class for the table and its working now!!!  thanks everyone for your effort to help me! :-)

Answer (score 2):

I got the solution! it was due to the `disableSelection()` mentioned for the `table`'s class. I removed that class for the table and its working now!!! Thanks everyone for your effort to help me! :-)